# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: java, android

java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

This error is coming when I add the BLE device in the list and click on the back button. if I click on that button without adding a BLE device then it won't crash.

Comment: Add your Java and XML code to your question

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Specify error part correctly

Answer (score -1):

If your layout is a LinearLayout the layout params class must be a LinearLayout.LayoutParams, if it's a ConstraintLayout then ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams, and so on. Those LayoutParams classes have specific methods for each layout type which are not mutually compatible